# Use a string property value as another class's declared instance in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to use the value of `MarketSymbol` property of my `Order` class to call methods inside my `Market` class,

`Order` class is:

```
public class Order
{
    public string MarketSymbol { get; set; }
}
```

`MarketSymbol` would exactly be either **ETH_USDT** or **BTC_USDT**.

which are the exact instances of `Market` class,

```
var ETH_USDT = new Market();
var BTC_USDT = new Market();
```

so while trying to call a method inside `Market` which is:

```
public class Market
{
    public Market()
    {
         // some code
    }


    public SimpleMethod()
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

I want to use the value of `MarketSymbol` to call the methods inside `Market` class

this is because I don't want to use a switch case or multiple if conditions,
I also would like to know if it's wrong to do this

Comment: What do you mean by "another class's instance name"? Objects don't have "names" in general. Did you mean *variables*? If so, typically you'd use a `Dictionary<string, Market>` instead of trying to declare variables dynamically (which isn't really a thing...)

Comment: You can use reflection for this. During the runtime, you can fetch the value of the `MarketSymbol` and add a new property to your class using that value

Comment: @OlegI: You can't add properties to classes at execution time, in general. Did you mean setting the value of an existing property, or something else?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question so that it's absolutely clear. The question should stand alone, without anyone having to read comments to understand it.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right, it seems you can only build the new types from scratch during the runtime using `TypeBuilder`(System.Reflection.Emit assembly) not extend exciting types. Anyway it seems the question isn't about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you could make a dictionary of Markets, where the key is a string.

Consider the example:

```
// Your class with some functions

public class Market
{
    public Market()
    {

    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Create your `Market` objects and populate a dictionary. Here you  can use the string you wanted to use for `MarketSymbol`:

```
Market BTC_USDT = new Market();
Market ETH_USDT = new Market();

Dictionary<string, Market> Markets = new Dictionary<string, Market>();

Markets.Add("BTC_USDT", BTC_USDT);
Markets.Add("ETH_USDT", ETH_USDT);
```

Now you can access all of the markets in your dictionary, by using that string as an indexer, no need for a case or whatever:

```
Markets["BTC_USDT"].SomeMethod();
```